# How to find a Lax pair

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hamilton-equations, lax-pair

I've been getting into Hamiltonian PDE's lately and they give the KdV equation a lax pair to proof that it is integrable in some sense.

My question is the following how does on find a lax-pair if we just start from an hamiltonian PDE or more specific how did they find it for the KdV-equation.

Or was it just guessing?